# Controlled distribution through AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

I know there is a B2B program to do this, that is not available in my region. But I want users to download the app from AppStore and use the features they bought license for (not in-app purchase but externally). Can we use configuration profiles here?

Comment: Cannot you just use external authorisation system with login in the app?

Comment: @atastrumf There is a hierarchical login present in this solution which has some glitches in implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no settings available in AppStore for doing that.

I have an app in AppStore, for which I implemented such a mechanism. What I did was:

1. When user launches my app, it'll ask for a PIN
2. This PIN can be bought externally (through our website or sales wing)
3. When they enter the PIN, I'm validating the purchase and configures the app
4. I'm checking the available feature for that particular user, and disables the not-yet purchased ones

Comment: In this case, there is always a server check whether the pin is valid and what features are available for that user. Instead can we use some kind of license file that is associated with that user? I thought configuration profile could be a solution.

Comment: @Sammy87: Not always, I'm asking PIN only one time. Later I check when user opens the app each day. Yes there will be server check.